# How can I evaluate a users code input in my web application

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, codemirror

I am attempting to build a demo site to help others learn to code. I am having a problem with evaluating a users input from code. I know that I can use the `eval()` function, but I am going to have a lot of examples and having many `eval()` functions doesn't seem very optimal or concise. If I were to use `eval()`, what would be the best way to implement this for best practices?

Or, is there a way that I can implement a simple compiler or a generic function and assign a button click to run said function that will evaluate the code in the editor and display it on the page somewhere.

I am currently using [Ace](https://ace.c9.io/#nav=api&api=editor) for my editor. Maybe there is a function in their api that does this, but I couldn't find it. I also know that I can use code mirror, but unsure of their solutions also. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

[Here](https://jsbin.com/nacani/edit?output) is a link to the JSBIN (Note: the code editor doesn't show up here as I can't require the library.

[Here](http://joshuadavidinc.com/learntocode/) is a link to the site that I have the functioning version on.

If you need to see the code I have posted it below:

**HTML**

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
  <title>Learn to Code with Codesmith</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.4.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
  <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400;300' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
  <link href='style.css' rel='stylesheet'>
  <style type="text/css" media="screen">

  </style>
</head>
<body>

  <!-- <div class="page-wrapper">
    <a class="btn trigger" href="javascript:;">Click Me!</a>
  </div> -->
  <div class="modal-wrapper">
    <div class="modal">
      <div class="head">
        <a class="btn-close trigger" href="javascript:;"></a>
      </div>
      <div class="content">
        <form class="" action="" method="post">
          <input id="username" type="text" name="name" value="" placeholder="Username">
          <input id="password" type="text" name="name" value="" placeholder="Password">
          <button id="login-submit" type="button" name="button">LOGIN</button>
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="menu">

    <!-- Menu icon -->
    <div class="icon-close">
      <img src="http://s3.amazonaws.com/codecademy-content/courses/ltp2/img/uber/close.png">
    </div>

    <!-- Menu -->
    <ul>
      <li class="main-cat"><a href="#">FOUNDATIONS</a></li>
      <ul>
        <li class="sub-cat"><a href="#">Intro to Javascript</a></li>
        <li class="sub-cat"><a href="#">Algorithms</a></li>
        <li class="sub-cat"><a href="#">Data Structures</a></li>
        <li class="sub-cat"><a href="#">Data Types</a></li>
        <li class="sub-cat"><a href="#">Syntax</a></li>
        <li class="sub-cat"><a href="#">Variables</a></li>
        <li class="sub-cat"><a href="#">Strings</a></li>
        <li class="sub-cat"><a href="#">Arrays</a></li>
        <li class="sub-cat"><a href="#">Objects</a></li>
        <li class="sub-cat"><a href="#">Functions</a></li>
        <li class="sub-cat"><a href="#">Scope</a></li>
      </ul>
      <li class="main-cat"><a href="#">Intermediate</a></li>
      <li class="main-cat"><a href="#">Advanced</a></li>

    </ul>
  </div>



  <!-- Main body -->
  <div class="nav">

    <button class="sign-up" type="button" name="button" onclick="">SIGN UP</button>

    <!-- <a class="btn trigger" href="javascript:;">Click Me!</a> -->
    <!-- <button class="login trigger" type="button" name="button" onclick="">LOGIN</button> -->
    <a class="login trigger" type="button" name="button" onclick="" href="javascript:;">LOGIN</a>

    <div class="icon-menu">
      <i class="fa fa-bars"></i>
      Menu
    </div>

  <div class="video">
    <iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/JeyH_8pWVJ4" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
  </div>

  <div class="code-snippet sandbox">
    <pre id="editor"> // Write your code here and when finished, click the run button below...
    <!-- function greeting() {
      console.log("Hello, World!");
    } -->
    </pre>



    <div id="run-code">
      <button class="run-code" type="button" name="button" onclick="evaluate()" >RUN</button>
    </div>
  </div>

  <!-- <textarea class="code-eval" name="output" rows="8" cols="40"></textarea> -->


  <!-- <a class="jsbin-embed" href="http://jsbin.com/iwovaj/73/embed?html,output&height=315px&width=700px"></a>
  <script src="http://static.jsbin.com/js/embed.js"></script> -->

  <script src="src-noconflict/ace.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
  <script>
      var editor = ace.edit("editor");
      editor.setTheme("ace/theme/chaos");
      editor.session.setMode("ace/mode/javascript");
      editor.session.getLength(true);
      document.getElementById('editor').style.fontSize='14px';
      editor.getSession().setUseWrapMode(true);
      editor.setHighlightActiveLine(true);
  </script>
  <script src="sandbox.js"></script>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script></script>
  <script src="app.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

**CSS**

```
html, body{
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
  margin:0;
}

body {
    overflow: hidden;
    left: 0;
    margin: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
}
#editor {
    margin: 0;
    position: relative;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    width: 700px;
    height: 315px;
}
.code-snippet {
  margin:0 auto;
  display: block;
  float: right;
  padding: 40px 40px;

}

.run-code {
  background-color: #1fbad6;
  border: 3px solid #1fbad6;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  margin-top: 40px;
  margin-bottom: 40px;
  outline: none;
  font:1.125em 'Arial', sans-serif;
  font-weight:700;
  text-align:center;
  text-decoration:none;
  color:#fff;
  border-radius:5px;
  float: right;
}

.video {
  position: relative;
  float: left;
  padding: 40px 40px;
}
/*.jsbin-embed {
  position: relative;
  float: right;
  width: 700px;
  height: 315px;
  padding: 40px 40px;
}*/

/* Initial menu */
.menu {
  background: #202024 url('http://s3.amazonaws.com/codecademy-content/courses/ltp2/img/uber/black-thread.png') repeat left top;
  left: -285px;  /* start off behind the scenes */
  height: 100%;
  position: fixed;
  width: 285px;
}

/* Basic styling */

.nav {
  /*background-image: url('http://s3.amazonaws.com/codecademy-content/courses/ltp2/img/uber/bg.png');*/
  background-color: #202020;
  height: 75px;
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
     -moz-background-size: cover;
       -o-background-size: cover;
          background-size: cover;
}

.menu ul {
  border-top: 1px solid #636366;
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.menu li {
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  line-height: 45px;
  padding-bottom: 3px;
  padding-left: 20px;
  padding-top: 3px;
}

.main-cat {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #636366;
  color: #03A3EA;
}

.sub-cat li {
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  line-height: 45px;
  padding-bottom: 3px;
  padding-left: 20px;
  padding-top: 3px;
}

.menu a {
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 15px;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

.icon-close {
  cursor: pointer;
  padding-left: 10px;
  padding-top: 10px;
}

.icon-menu {
  color: #1fbad6;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  font-size: 20px;
  padding-bottom: 25px;
  padding-left: 25px;
  padding-top: 25px;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

.icon-menu i {
  margin-right: 5px;
}

.login {
  position: relative;
  float: right;
  margin-top: 18px;
  margin-right: 20px;
  padding: 5px 15px;
  font-size: 18px;
  color: #1fbad6;
  background: none;
  border: 3px solid #1fbad6;
  font:1.125em 'Arial', sans-serif;
  font-weight:700;
  text-align:center;
  text-decoration:none;
  border-radius:5px;
}

.sign-up {
  position: relative;
  float: right;
  margin-top: 18px;
  margin-right: 20px;
  padding: 5px 15px;
  font-size: 18px;
  color: #1fbad6;
  background: none;
  border: 3px solid #1fbad6;
  font:1.125em 'Arial', sans-serif;
  font-weight:700;
  text-align:center;
  text-decoration:none;
  border-radius:5px;
}


/* ============ MODAL ========== */


.page-wrapper{
  width:100%;
  height: 100%;
/* //background:url(http://i.imgur.com/2ZgHKbQ.jpg) center no-repeat;
  //background-size:cover;*/
}

.blur{
  -webkit-filter: blur(5px);
  -moz-filter: blur(5px);
  -o-filter: blur(5px);
  -ms-filter: blur(5px);
  filter: blur(5px);
}

a.btn{
  width:150px;
  display:block;
  margin:-25px 0 0 -75px;
  padding:1em 0;
  position:absolute;
  top:50%; left:50%;
  font:1.125em 'Arial', sans-serif;
  font-weight:700;
  text-align:center;
  text-decoration:none;
  color:#fff;
  border-radius:5px;
  background:rgba(217,67,86,1);
}

.modal-wrapper{
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
  position:fixed;
  top:0; left:0;
  background:rgba(64,64,64,1);
  visibility:hidden;
  opacity:0;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.25s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: all 0.25s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: all 0.25s ease-in-out;
  transition: all 0.25s ease-in-out;
  z-index: 999;
}

.modal-wrapper.open{
  opacity:1;
  visibility:visible;
}

.modal{
  width:600px;
  height:400px;
  display:block;
  margin:50% 0 0 -300px;
  position:relative;
  top:50%; left:50%;
  background:#fff;
  opacity:0;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
  transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
}

.modal-wrapper.open .modal{
  margin-top:-200px;
  opacity:1;
}

.head{
  width:90%;
  height:32px;
  padding:1.5em 5%;
  overflow:hidden;
  background:#01bce5;
}

.btn-close{
  width:32px;
  height:32px;
  display:block;
  float:right;
}

.btn-close::before, .btn-close::after{
  content:'';
  width:32px;
  height:6px;
  display:block;
  background:#fff;
}

.btn-close::before{
  margin-top:12px;
  -webkit-transform:rotate(45deg);
  -moz-transform:rotate(45deg);
  -o-transform:rotate(45deg);
  transform:rotate(45deg);
}

.btn-close::after{
  margin-top:-6px;
  -webkit-transform:rotate(-45deg);
  -moz-transform:rotate(-45deg);
  -o-transform:rotate(-45deg);
  transform:rotate(-45deg);
}

.content{
  padding:5%;
}

#username {
  width: 95%;
  background: none;
  border: 3px solid #1fbad6;
  padding: 12px;
  margin-bottom: 40px;
  outline: none;
  font:1.125em 'Arial', sans-serif;
  font-weight:700;
  text-decoration:none;
  border-radius:5px;
  color: #202020;
}

#password {
  width: 95%;
  background: none;
  border: 3px solid #1fbad6;
  padding: 12px;
  margin-bottom: 40px;
  outline: none;
  font:1.125em 'Arial', sans-serif;
  font-weight:700;
  text-decoration:none;
  border-radius:5px;
  color: #202020;
}

#login-submit {
  background-color: #1fbad6;
  border: 3px solid #1fbad6;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  margin-bottom: 40px;
  outline: none;
  font:1.125em 'Arial', sans-serif;
  font-weight:700;
  text-align:center;
  text-decoration:none;
  color:#fff;
  border-radius:5px;
  float: right;
}
```

**JAVASCRIPT**

```
var main = function() {
  /* Push the body and the nav over by 285px over */
  $('.icon-menu').click(function() {
    $('.menu').animate({
      left: "0px"
    }, 100);

    $('body').animate({
      left: "285px"
    }, 100);
  });

  /* Then push them back */
  $('.icon-close').click(function() {
    $('.menu').animate({
      left: "-285px"
    }, 100);

    $('body').animate({
      left: "0px"
    }, 100);
  });
};


/* ========== Evaluate Code ========== */

var app = {};

// go through the application and find every single instance of a div
// with the class of 'sandbox'
app.bootstrap = function() {
  var sandboxes = document.getElementsByClassName('sandbox');

  // for each sandbox, run the createSandbox function
  [].forEach.call(sandboxes, app.createSandbox);
};

// given a parent element, find the first textarea inside and
// create a sandbox around it
app.createSandbox = function(parent) {
  var textarea = parent.getElementsByTagName('textarea')[0],
      // create an instance of Sandbox using this textarea
      sandbox = Sandbox(textarea);

  parent.appendChild(sandbox.label);
};

// when the DOM loads bootstrap the application
window.addEventListener('load', app.bootstrap);

// Sandbox class
// This class is based around a textarea element, which will contain
// the code. However, it could just as easily be the DOM element for
// an Ace/Codemirror editor.
function Sandbox(textarea) {
  var sandbox = {};

  // create a label to show output
  sandbox.label = document.createElement('label');
  sandbox.label.setAttribute('class', 'output');
  sandbox.label.addEventListener('click', evaluate);

  // evaluate code whenever there is input into the textarea
  textarea.addEventListener('input', evaluate);
  sandbox.textarea = textarea;

  // initial resize and evaluation
  resize();
  evaluate();

  // resize to within the appropriate height for the textarea
  function resize() {
    var scrollHeight = textarea.scrollHeight;

    if(scrollHeight > Sandbox.MAX_HEIGHT) {
      height = Sandbox.MAX_HEIGHT;
    } else if(scrollHeight < Sandbox.MIN_HEIGHT) {
      height = Sandbox.MIN_HEIGHT;
    } else {
      height = scrollHeight;
    }

    textarea.style.height = height + 'px';
  }

  // evaluate the code within the textarea
  function evaluate() {
    // get the code
    var src = textarea.value,
    // create a console proxy (for logging to the label)
        console = Sandbox.consoleProxy(sandbox.label);

    // clear the output first
    sandbox.label.innerText = '';
    // try the eval and catch errors to send to the console
    try {
      /* jshint ignore:start */
      eval(src);
      /* jshint ignore:end */
    } catch(err) {
      console.error(err);
    }
  }

  return sandbox;
}

// config
Sandbox.MAX_HEIGHT = 500;
Sandbox.MIN_HEIGHT = 50;

// A function which spoofs the native console object, by writing
// text to output elements, rather than the dev tools console.
Sandbox.consoleProxy = function(element) {
  return {
    log: function(message) {
      message = [].join.call(arguments, ' ');
      element.innerText += (message + '\n');
      element.setAttribute('disabled', false);
      // write to the original console too
      console.log.apply(console, arguments);
    },
    error: function(message) {
      element.setAttribute('disabled', true);
      element.innerText = message;
    }
  };
};


/* ========== Modal  ========== */

$('.trigger').click(function() {
     $('.modal-wrapper').toggleClass('open');
    $('.page-wrapper').toggleClass('blur');
     return false;
  });

$(document).ready(main);
```

Answer (score 3):

`eval` is the defacto way to run code. It has a less than great reputation because of its affiliation with security vulnerabilities, however, if that's not a concern and users will be running their own code in a sandbox, that is exactly what `eval` is designed to do and it does it well.

Implementing a simple compiler for Javascript is no small undertaking, however if you were confident that this was the right approach, you can make use of open source projects such as [esprima](http://esprima.org/demo/parse.html) to do some of the heavy lifting for you, when it comes to parsing and evaluating code.

I developed a generic code evaluation widget for a project I worked on in the past, simply using `<textarea>` and `eval`. It supports sandboxing of the console for logs and errors. It might be helpful to look through [the code](https://gist.github.com/danprince/e46038576345989c2559).

Comment: Thank you Dan! I believe your approach will work best for this. Is there any way that I can see your application? Also, as I am still a bit wet behind the ears, what would be the best way for me to implement your method. This is my thought process, please tell me how far off base I am... Create a `<textarea>` in my HTML, Also create a `<div>` with the class of sandbox in which your App will assign a sandbox. I can then assign my "Run" `<button>` click to the `evaluate( )` function and it would work for each different input?

Comment: [Here's the application](http://danprince.github.io/improvise/). You wouldn't even need to create text areas if you are already using Ace. If you put an evaluate button with each Ace editor, then you can pull the code straight out of it and evaluate it in the same way.

Comment: Ok, going to check out the app and try to implement it this way. If I have any trouble is it ok to contact you again? Also for clarification, let's say I have a `class="editor"` for my code editor how would the evaluate button know evaluate the editor? Would I just replace `<textarea>` with "editor"?

Comment: Sure, either leave a comment here, or find my contact details on my profile. I've updated [the gist](https://gist.github.com/danprince/e46038576345989c2559) with comments. Hopefully that will help.

Comment: Thank you again. I really appreciate it. I have looked through the comments and everything is very thorough. I have added your source to my file as well as the sandbox class to my Ace `<div>` so that now looks like this: `<div class="code-snippet sandbox">` I also added the `execute()` function to the `onclick` of my button and have no results, but I am getting an error. Can you show me what I am doing wrong? I have updated the code above to mirror what I have done. Also http://joshuadavidinc.com/learntocode/ on the live version.